# Alternative to the 'hash parameters' limitation of query-params in link-to helper in Ember

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to pass a hash from a model as the query params to the link-to helper?

For example, I have a model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  val1: DS.attr('string'),
  val2: DS.attr('string'),
  asHash: Ember.computed('val1', 'val2', function() {
    'val1': this.get('val1'),
    'val2': this.get('val2'),
  })
});
```

And in a component I want to use that value like:

```
<div>
  {{#link-to 'query-page' (query-params model.asHash)}}query{{/link-to}}
</div>
```

The example above results in an error:

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The `query-params` helper only accepts hash parameters, e.g. (query-params queryParamPropertyName='foo') as opposed to just (query-params 'foo')

Any ideas on how this can be worked around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible, `(query-params)` needs property name for query value you are passing `queryParamPropertyName='foo'`, instead of passing model as queryparam you can pass it directly `link-to` `{{#link-to 'my-route' model }}query{{/link-to}}` but `my-route` should support it.

Comment: Marking "not possible" as the correct answer. Thank you.